# Eclipe LUNA - "The import java.sql cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Eclipse LUNA and JDK 8 installed on my computer.
I get the message "The import java.sql cannot be resolved" on the import lines.

i checked the jre definition (windows -> reference -> java -> installed JREs
and it is setup there to the folder of the jre on my computer.

what is the problem?

Comment: Make sure you jave jre libraries in your classpath.

Comment: And you created a fresh workspace?

Comment: I use existing project

Comment: Darshan Lila - how can I do this?

Comment: Expand the JRE System Library mode in your project using the Package Explorer view and visually verify that java.sql is actually there. If not, remove it from the Installed JREs page and then re-add it, close the project from the File menu and then reopen it. Otherwise, Clean and Build it again.

Answer (score 6):

Right click on project - >BuildPath - >Configure BuildPath - >Libraries tab - >

Double click on JRE SYSTEM LIBRARY - >Then select alternate JRE

Try this..
After that once clean your project too..

Answer (score 1):

You can also try declaring a dependency

```
requires java.sql;
```

on your module-descriptor file(module-info.java).

Answer (score 0):

It is my experience that workspaces do not always work correctly after upgrading Eclipse to a newer version.

Recreate your workspace from your version control system.

Comment: Switch to a new, non-existing workspace and reestablish your projects in it.

Comment: If you do not yet have stored your source code in a version control system, now is the perfect time to to do so.

Comment: Great. Then you have even better conditions for learning about version control.