# 'the import java.sql cannot be resolved' eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I am getting this error while trying to work with MySql and Java. I have downloaded the right .jar file and I added it to the Project->Properties->java Build Path->both ModulePath and ClassPath just in case. I am still getting the error. I found out that I need to write "requires java.sql" inside the module, and it does solve my problem, but then when I run it say "Class Module could not be found". Without this line (just the empty module) works fine, but I still have that initial error. What should I do?

Comment: Hi, Follow this link [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712858/eclipe-luna-the-import-java-sql-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: Is the MySQL driver library modularized? If not, you need to stick to traditional classpaths.

Comment: @nitind Hi, I am quite new and know nothing about what is a modularized library, classpaths or traditional classpaths.Would you mind explaining or directing me to some links that could help?Also, I found out that the module acts the same whenever I type anything like "requires 'some library name' ",I get the error "java.lang.module.FindException:Module 'project name' not found". I found someone on StackOverflow who advised fixing the VM Arguments in the 'Run Configurations', but I couldn't understand what paths they included there. One argument was like '-p "path/classes".Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include  a string **"requires java.sql;"** into the module-info.java.

module-info.java is a module that provides a module descriptor—metadata that specifies the module’s dependencies, the packages the module makes available to other modules, and more.

**requires:-** A requires module directive specifies that this module depends on another module which means it specifies **module dependency**.